# Custom shopping cart error: Can't use function return value in write context

Tags: php, cart

I am making a small shopping cart system for my website, but there is an error which I can't resolve. It's coming from my cart() function. Below you can see my whole code, any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
<?php
session_start();

$page = 'shop.php';

mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('_cart') or die(mysql_error());

if (isset($_GET['add'])) {
  $quantity = mysql_query('SELECT id, quantity FROM products WHERE id='.mysql_real_escape_string((int)$_GET['add']));
  while ($quantity_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($quantity)) {
        if ($quantity_row['quantity'] != $_SESSION['cart_'.(int)$_GET['add']]) {
           $_SESSION['cart_'.(int)$_GET['add']] + '1';
        }
  }
  header('Location: '.$page);
}

if (isset($_GET['remove'])) {
   $_SESSION['cart_'.(int)$_GET['remove']]--;
   header('Location: '.$page);
}

if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {
   $_SESSION['cart_'.(int)$_GET['delete']]='0';
   header('Location: '.$page);
}

function paypal_items() {
  $num = 0;
  foreach ($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
    if ($value != 0) {
     if (substr($name, 0, 5)=='cart_') {
       $id = substr($name, 5, strlen($name)-5);
       $get = mysql_query('SELECT id, name, price, shipping FROM products WHERE id='.mysql_real_escape_string((int)$id));
       while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {
         $num++;
         echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_number_'.$num.'" value="'.$id.'">';
         echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_name_'.$num.'" value="'.$get_row['name'].'">';
         echo '<input type="hidden" name="amount_'.$num.'" value="'.$get_row['price'].'">';
         echo '<input type="hidden" name="shipping_'.$num.'" value="'.$get_row['shipping'].'">';
         echo '<input type="hidden" name="shipping2_'.$num.'" value="'.$get_row['shipping'].'">';
         echo '<input type="hidden" name="quantity_'.$num.'" value="'.$value.'">';
       }
     }
    }
  }
}

function cart() {
  foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
    if ($value>0) {
      if (substr($name, 0, 5) = 'cart_') {
         $id = substr($name, 5, (strlen($name)-5));
         $get = mysql_query('SELECT id, name, price FROM products WHERE id='.mysql_real_escape_string((int)$id));
         while($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {
           $sub = $get_row['price']*$value;
           echo $get_row['name'].' x '.$value.' @ &euro;'.number_format($get_row['price'], 2).' = &euro;'.number_format($sub, 2).'<a href="cart.php?remove='.$id.'">[-]</a> <a href="cart.php?add='.$id.'">[+]</a> <a href="cart.php?delete='.$id.'">[Delete]</a><br />';
         }
      }
      $total += $sub;
    }
  }
  if ($total==0) {
     echo "Your cart is empty.";
  } else {
     echo '<p>Total: &euro;'.number_format($total, 2).'</p>';
     ?>
     <p>
     <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
     <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
     <input type="hidden" name="business" value="pavel@bgtracker-studios.com">
     <?php paypal_items(); ?>
     <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
     <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $total; ?>">
     <input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but03.gif" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
     </form>
     </p>
     <?php

  }
}

function products() {
  $get = mysql_query('SELECT id, name, description, price FROM products WHERE quantity > 0 ORDER BY id DESC');
  if (mysql_num_rows($get)==0) {
    echo "There are no products to display!";
  } else {
    while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {
          echo '<p>'.$get_row['name'].'<br />'.$get_row['description'].'<br />&euro;'.number_format($get_row['price'], 2).' <a href="cart.php?add='.$get_row['id'].'">Add</a></p>';
    }
  }
}

?>
```

I get the following error when I call the function cart(). "Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in E:\xampp\htdocs\cart.php on line 53"

And line 53 is inside the cart() function:

```
if (substr($name, 0, 5) = 'cart_') {
```

Comment: You have both `if (substr($name, 0, 5) = 'cart_')` and `if (substr($name, 0, 5)=='cart_') {` you're missing an `=` sign ***perhaps?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be attempting a comparison in that `if()`, you should be using double equals signs, a la `==`. A single equals sign is for assigning a value.

That code should be

```
if (substr($name, 0, 5) == 'cart_') {
```

Comment: *That code should be

`if (substr($name, 0, 5) = 'cart_') {`* oh? Double-check that ;-)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice that I missed the second equals sign. But now I have one little problem, it's saying that my $total variable is not defined and my other functions don't work properly because of that.

Comment: @PavelNozharov well, you haven't defined `$total` anywhere, you just randomly use it in your `cart()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code is actually both correct and incorrect:

```
if (substr($name, 0, 5) =='cart_') { // This version is right
if (substr($name, 0, 5) ='cart_') {  // This version is not
```

Remember the difference between `=` and `==`.

```
=  // Assignment
== // Comparison
```

Comment: His posted code contains both double and single equals signs, respectively in the `paypal_items()` function and the `cart()` function.